# Does anyone know the distance in pixels between the top of the phone screen to the start of the image preview in the camera?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to build a custom camera overlay and need to know the height of the black toolbar just above the image preview when taking a photo. Does anyone know this? picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an answer to your question by logging the view hierarchy of interest.

Make a recursive view logging function, something like...

```
    func logsubviews(view: UIView, indent: Int)->Void {
             //indenting
            var indent = indent + 1
            var indentString = ""
            for i in 0..<indent {
                indentString = " \(indentString)"
            }
            //logging
            println("\(indentString) \(view)")
            for subview in view.subviews {
                self.logsubviews(subview as UIView, indent: indent)
            }
        }
```

Then log the imagePicker's view hierarchy after you have presented it:

```
@IBAction func invokeImagePicker(sender: AnyObject) {
        let imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion:{
            ()->Void in
            self.logsubviews(imagePicker.view, indent: 0)
        })
    }
```

You will get a nice printout of the imagePickerController's views and their respective frames.